# R Highcharter zoom selected area

Tags: r, shiny, r-highcharter

Is it possible to store coordinates of the zoomed area in highcharter with shiny app?

I would like something similar to this [example's](https://jsfiddle.net/dhptnfkt/37/):

```
function getSelection(event) {
    alert(event.xAxis[0].min);
    alert(event.xAxis[0].max);
}
```

but instead of alert, just to store them and use them.

The sample shiny app:

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(highcharter)
library(tidyr)

df_plot <- cbind(
  seq(0, 1, by = 0.1),
  sample(seq(from = 100, to = 300, by = 10), size = 11, replace = TRUE),
  sample(seq(from = 1, to = 100, by = 9), size = 11, replace = TRUE),
  sample(seq(from = 50, to = 60, by = 2), size = 11, replace = TRUE),
  sample(seq(from = 100, to = 130, by = 1), size = 1, replace = TRUE)
) %>% as.data.frame()

names(df_plot) <- c("x", "a", "b", "c", "d")


ui <- fluidPage(
  column(
    width = 3,
    selectInput("select", "Select var:", choices = c("a", "b", "x", "y"), selected = c("a", "b", "x"), multiple = TRUE)
  ),
  column(
    width = 9
  ),
  column(
    width = 12,
    highchartOutput("plot")
  )
)

server <-  function(input, output){

  output$plot <- renderHighchart({
    highchart() %>%
      hc_xAxis(categories = df_plot$x) %>%
      hc_add_series(data = df_plot$a) %>%
      hc_add_series(data = df_plot$b, yAxis = 1) %>%
      hc_yAxis_multiples(
        list(lineWidth = 3, lineColor='#7cb5ec', title=list(text="First y-axis")),
        list(lineWidth = 3, lineColor="#434348", title=list(text="Second y-axis"))) %>%
      hc_chart(
        zoomType = "x"
      )
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do somethig like this:

```
library(shiny)
library(highcharter)


ui <- fluidPage(
  column(8,highchartOutput("hcout")),
  column(4,textOutput("eventout"))
  )

server <- function(input, output) {

   output$hcout <- renderHighchart({

     highcharts_demo() %>% 
       hc_chart(
         zoomType = "xy",
         events = list(
           selection = JS("function(event) {
                        Shiny.onInputChange('event', [event.xAxis[0].min,     event.xAxis[0].max]);
                          return true;
                          } ")
         )
       ) 

   })

   output$eventout <- renderText({ 

     input$event
     })

}
```

But I don't know why the `reset zoom` button don't work (as same the jsfiddle example when you enable the `resetZoomButton`)